# Need an easy WinAPI grid in C

Tags: c, winapi, gridview

I am looking for a grid control that can be controlled via WinAPI messages. I have tried the BabyGrid from CodeGuru but it is very slow when it comes to displaying on large screen.

Anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/listview.aspx) with Report style is not enough ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not enough. I need something that has more features, I need it to display and edit database records.

Comment: If you want to edit cells, you could use this code http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListsiEdit.aspx. It works with an Edit subclass procedure.
What more features are you misssing ? Or do you want to avoid to mess with the win32 API ?

Answer (score 0):

*Use any of the native Win32 grids controls. Ask on Adv. Win32 group for sample code (C/Win32)*

Yes, there are several built-in Win32 Grid controls (documented, MS, and undocumented)
C code had also been posted on IRC
(and apparently a kid is playing by removing answers from Microsoft experts (Shell team)... pathetic)

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the native Win32 grids controls.
Ask on [Adv. Win32 group](http://tinyurl.com/cmhb5g) for sample code (C/Win32)